# Copying a selected range of data using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet to another as efficiently as possible.

I've created a block of code which stores a variable range into a variable, what I have then attempted to do is use this variable to copy across directly to a cell in another worksheet. Upon trying this I get a compile error, any assistance would be appreciated. I'm fairly new at writing fresh VBA code and going through a long process of speeding up code written by the macro recorder.

Thanks

Please find the code below:

```
Sub M_MigrateAssessmentDates()
'
' M_MigrateAssessmentDates Macro
'

'   Select and copy data - code checked for referencing issues 3/10/2019
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A2", "E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    AssData.Select.myRange.Copy AssDates.Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Well..... You're using a variable as a method of a select method. Doesn't make sense? It's not supposed to. `Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value` is what you need to be doing. Is `AssData` a codename for a worksheet? I assume not since you're new to VBA... I don't see it declared or set anywhere either btw.

Comment: AssData and AssDates are both codenames for worksheets, I'm unsure how that would copy the data across to AssDates? AssData is the worksheet being copied frm and AssDates the one being copied to, I have coded all the worksheets in case someone changes a name in my absence.

Comment: Hmm okay. So you need to qualify the `myRange` with the worksheet when you __Set__ it, not afterwards. `Set myRange = AssData.Range( ... )`

Comment: I'm am still experiencing issues pasting the data, the source cell is part of an excel table and when I paste inside it it is limited by the number of empty rows inside that excel table. So for instance, if there are 830 rows of data and 700 empty rows available in the table only 700 rows of data will be copied across. I could bolster the number of empty rows in the table however this is not ideal. Is there a way to copy and at the same time paste rows into the table. I had a macro running using it's automated code which seemed to work using the paste as values function?